# create an instance of a Stream to output data

Tags: c#, .net, bloomberg

I am using an API from Bloomberg. I'm having some issues with the request I am sending. However the request type has a method called Print.

The method is shown below. I haven't really used streams before. I can't seem to create an instance of a Stream variable either. Am I supposed to supply a text file or something where it will print some output?

```
request.Print(System.IO.Stream output)
```

Comment: Did you check the original documentation on how to use the class?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes but I don't really follow it and how I'm supposed to it for this method

Comment: You can do several things, you can open a FileStream and give that one in the Print function I think. Or just create a Stream()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stream` is an abstract class so you can't create instances of it, but you can pass any `Stream` subclass instance, for example

```
request.Print(File.OpenRead(pathToFile))
```

Check the article on inheritance in C# on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx).

Comment: I'm getting an error message saying stream was not writable? I have request.Print(File.OpenRead(@"C:\MyPath\Myfile.txt"));

Comment: Try `File.Open(pathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)`